# Dart Editor bitwise XOR showing as unknown

Tags: dart, dart-editor

The current version of Dart Editor is showing the bitwise XOR operator as `not defined for class bool`

I don't see it defined in `num.dart` either.

Ex:

```
bool x = a ^ b;
```

The editor shows the "Caret" as not defined.

**Update**:
Dart's api spec only allows bitwise XOR on integers. I fixed my code to properly work with `bool`s.

Comment: This is a good question, and good answer. Why don't you add your update an answer so it's marked as answered?

Comment: I got this from a [dart-sdk GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/530#issuecomment-443135516): "For the record, since Dart 2.1, the bool class has had non-short-circuit operators &, | and ^." So nowadays it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from the question, so that this appears as answered...)

[Dart's spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf) only allows bitwise XOR on integers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the XOR operator on booleans since Dart version 2.1

> [...] since Dart 2.1, the `bool` class has had non-short-circuit operators `&`, `|` and `^`.
>
> They can be used where you want both sides to be evaluated, and, especially for `^`, they can be used in assignments: `bool parity = false; while (something) parity ^= checkSomething();`.

Taken from the corresponding [Github issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/530#issuecomment-443135516).

See the dart documentation for XOR [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/bool/operator_bitwise_exclusive_or.html).